# Jersey Restful failed with error "java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor"

Tags: java, jersey

The simple restful code based on Jersey

```java
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

import com.yakima.core.webservice.resource.UserResource;
import org.glassfish.jersey.jettison.JettisonFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@ApplicationPath("/")
public class Servlet extends ResourceConfig{
Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(Servlet.class.getName());
public Servlet() {
    registerClasses(UserResource.class);
    register(new JettisonFeature());
    packages("com.yakima.core.webservice");
    log.info("--------------registered--------");
    }
}
```

resource class

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONException;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

@Path("/")
public class UserResource {
Logger log =  Logger.getLogger(UserResource.class.getName());

@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "dev")
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@Context
UriInfo uriInfo;

public UserResource() {
}

@GET @Path("ping")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public String getHeathCheck() {
    log.info("getHeathCheck");
    return "pang";
}
}
```

web.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
<display-name>my REST service</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.yakima.core.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>unit:dev</param-name>
        <param-value>persistence/dev</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<persistence-unit-ref>
    <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/dev</persistence-unit-ref-name>
    <persistence-unit-name>dev</persistence-unit-name>
</persistence-unit-ref>

</web-app>
```

persistence.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="dev" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dev"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
        <property name="toplink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

error shows below after deploy

```java
Jun 26, 2014 1:59:18 AM org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors logErrors
WARNING: The following warnings have been detected: WARNING: HK2 service reification failed for [com.yakima.core.webservice.resource.UserResource] with an exception:
MultiException stack 1 of 2
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Could not find a suitable constructor in com.yakima.core.webservice.resource.UserResource class.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.JerseyClassAnalyzer.getConstructor(JerseyClassAnalyzer.java:189)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.getConstructor(Utilities.java:183)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:129)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.initialize(ClazzCreator.java:182)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.internalReify(SystemDescriptor.java:649)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:604)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:417)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2099)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$900(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1046)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:636)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1025)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
MultiException stack 2 of 2
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Errors were discovered while reifying SystemDescriptor(
    implementation=com.yakima.core.webservice.resource.UserResource
    contracts={com.yakima.core.webservice.resource.UserResource}
    scope=org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScoped
    qualifiers={}
    descriptorType=CLASS
    descriptorVisibility=NORMAL
    metadata=
    rank=0
    loader=null
    proxiable=null
    proxyForSameScope=null
    analysisName=null
    id=144
    locatorId=2
    identityHashCode=701724234
    reified=false)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.reify(SystemDescriptor.java:615)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.reifyDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:417)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.narrow(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:2099)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.access$900(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:119)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1051)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl$8.compute(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1046)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture$1.call(LRUHybridCache.java:111)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache$OriginThreadAwareFuture.run(LRUHybridCache.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.utilities.cache.LRUHybridCache.compute(LRUHybridCache.java:292)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.internalGetDescriptor(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:1135)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:636)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceLocatorImpl.getService(ServiceLocatorImpl.java:626)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.inject.Injections.getOrCreate(Injections.java:172)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.MethodHandler$ClassBasedMethodHandler.getInstance(MethodHandler.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.PushMethodHandlerRouter.apply(PushMethodHandlerRouter.java:74)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage._apply(RoutingStage.java:115)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:94)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.routing.RoutingStage.apply(RoutingStage.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:261)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:252)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1025)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:372)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:382)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:345)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

```
libs
ls -l /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/webservice/WEB-INF/lib/
total 6648
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   14787 Jun 17 17:35 aopalliance-repackaged-2.3.0-b05.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  159444 Jun 17 17:35 hk2-api-2.3.0-b05.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  162326 Jun 17 17:35 hk2-locator-2.3.0-b05.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   82770 Jun 17 17:35 hk2-utils-2.3.0-b05.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  714194 Jun 17 17:35 javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   26366 Jun 17 17:35 javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7    5942 Jun 17 17:35 javax.inject-2.3.0-b05.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  112758 Jun 17 17:35 javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  151913 Jun 17 17:35 jersey-client-2.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  722711 Jun 18 13:41 jersey-common-2.9.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   15719 Jun 18 23:25 jersey-container-servlet-2.9.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   54943 Jun 18 12:16 jersey-container-servlet-core-2.9.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  962867 Jun 17 17:35 jersey-guava-2.9.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   46504 Jun 18 12:07 jersey-media-json-jettison-2.9.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7  915852 Jun 18 13:37 jersey-server-2.9.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   81899 Apr 29 11:37 jettison-1.3.5.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   20235 Jun 17 17:35 osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   53842 Jun 17 17:13 persistence-api-1.0.2.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   26514 Aug  1  2013 stax-api-1.0.1.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7 2370900 Jun 18 12:15 toplink-essentials-1.0.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat7 tomcat7   63777 Jun 18 12:03 validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
```

anything wrong? appreciate for any help

Answer (score 7):

Jersey resource instantiation expects a parameterless constructor. May be you should create a no-arg constructor from base class to all inherited classes.

Comment: This is only true for auto-discovered resources. But what do you need to do for hand-registered resources (which may have any constructor they like)?